# Can I use multiple sound cards with the same sound source at once?

Tags: windows-7, audio, replicate

Given a system with **two sound cards** (one onboard and the other USB):

Is it possible for me to configure Windows 7 (directly or with the help of third party software) to replicate/clone the audio output from any given application (VLC, etc) so that I hear the same output in both the sound cards?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: well, the idea is that if i have two head phones i would want to be able to hear the same output on both of them without running multiple machines or applications on the same machine...

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with the help of tools such as [Virtual Audio Cable](http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm).

This tool allows one to create a virtual audio device, the output to which can then be routed to other sound cards present in the system.